# Sage ('Python-like' language) Attribute error "IntegerListsLex_with_category.element_class" object

Tags: python, partition, sage

Given an integer k, I have programmed a way to take all partitions of k such that

(1) each partition has at most n entries (where n is also given)

(2) each partition does not have any repeated odd numbers.

I also categorized the list of these partitions in descending order. However, I am unable to append zeros to the end of any given partition in the list such that all the partitions are n-tuples.

```
# Define n and k
(k, n) = (10, 5)

# Find partitions of k of max length n, and put partitions in list B
B = Partitions(k, max_length=n).list()

# Extracts partitions with repeated odd components and creates a separate list for them, namely B_Repeated_Odds
B_Repeated_Odds = []
for i in range(0, len(B)):
    for j in range(0, len(B[i])):
        for l in range(0, len(B[i])):
            if B[i][j]%2 == 1:
                if B[i][l]%2 == 1:
                    if B[i][j] == B[i][l]:
                        if j != l:
                            B_Repeated_Odds.append(B[i])

# Remove duplicates from B_Repeated_Odds
B_Unique = uniq(B_Repeated_Odds)

# Remove unwanted partitions from original list B, and sort finalized list in descending order
Improper_Part = Set(B).difference(Set(B_Unique))
Proper_Part = sorted(Improper_Part, reverse=true)

for i in range(0, len(Proper_Part)):
    while len(Proper_Part[i]) < n:
        Proper_Part[i].append(0)
```

The aforementioned issue occurs in the last three lines of code, with an error message stating "Attribute Error: 'IntegerListsLex_with_category.element_class' object has no attribute 'append'."

My question specifically is how can I change the types of the partitions within the list Proper_Part from IntegerListsLex_with_category.element_class to list (or any other object where the append command is applicable)? Or if anyone sees a better approach, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the suitable replacement for the bottom three lines of code is the following:

```
# Convert each partition from IntegerListsLex_with_category.element object to list 
C = [] 
for i in range(0, len(Proper_Part)): 
    C.append(list(Proper_Part[i])) 
    while len(C[i]) < n: 
        C[i].append(0)
```